# How to perform reodering of cells in One-to-many relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, nsorderedset

I am learning `coreData` and I am new it, I have created a **one-to-many relationship of boss and employee,** (i.e one boss and many employees). So I am showing all the bosses on `firstTableView` and when the user clicks on the cells, he can view the employees assigned to each boss and also he can add employees to any particular boss. **Now I want to reorder the boss cells**. So how it should be done?

Edited based on the discussion below

```
   - (void)insertNewObject:(NSString *)fileName
{    
    Boss *bossName = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boss" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [bossName setName:fileName];

    NSManagedObject *lastObject = [self.controller.fetchedObjects lastObject];
    float lastObjectDisplayOrder = [[lastObject valueForKey:@"displayOrder"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f",lastObjectDisplayOrder);
    [bossName setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lastObjectDisplayOrder + 1.0] forKey:@"displayOrder"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Specific Answer To Updated Question]**

It would be either ....

```
[self.boss insertObject:newEmployeeObject inEmployeesAtIndex:0];
```

Which is a core-data generated method that is part of your Boss subclass if you choose to create subclasses from your model.  Or....

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *employees = [self.boss mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"employees"];
[employees insertObject:newEmployee atIndex:0]
```

It's not that intuitive I know, you can't just make a mutable copy, you have to get a special proxy object from `mutableOrderedSetValueForKey`.

---

**[Original General Answer]...**

Core-data now has the ability to use "Ordered Relationships" which you can specify in your model.  If you do so, relationships in your object model will be represented by a new class `NSOrderedSet` which is a hybrid of an `NSArray` and an `NSSet`.  By re-ordering the objects in this relationship object and saving the context you will reorder the objects in the database and they will maintain their new order.  This kind of ordered relationship tends to be used when there isn't natural ordering attribute on the object.  For instance the order simply represents the users preference for ordering a list in the UI.

If on the other hand you have an attribute on one of your objects that describes the order for a collection then you can use that attribute to order the results of an NSFetchRequest by specifying the `Sort Descriptors`.  The value of the attribute would specify the position the object would be in in the results of the `NSFetchRequest`.

If you are using `Ordered Relationships` you would need keep the order of the `NSOrderedSet` for that relationship and the `UITableView` in sync.  If the change was driven from the UI then you respond to the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods such as `- (void)moveRowAtIndex:(NSUInteger)sourceIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)destinationIndex` and use the information provided to move the corresponding object to it's new position in the core-data relationship either by using the proxy object from `mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:` or the Core-data generated accessors of a generated subclass.

If the change to order were driven from the data side you would use the methods on `UITableView` such as `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` to sync the rows in the `UITableView` with the changes you were making in the data.

If you are using `NSFetchRequest`s you have a similar task.  In this case you respond to user driven changes in the order by updating the sort attributes on your objects to match the new order that is described by the `UITableView` through the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate.  Or if the ordering changes are starting at the data side you update the `UITableView` through it's methods to match the changes you are making to the sort attributes on the data.  In this case you will be working with the results from the `NSFetchResults` as an `NSArray`, you would also have to keep that object in sync until the next time you ran the `NSFetchRequest`. You could use the same sort descriptor to sort the array, or create an `NSMutableArray` and use it's methods to move the data to match the table.

Finally if you are using `NSFetchRequest` you may like to look at `NSFetchedResultsController` It's job it is to simplify task of syncing a sorted `NSFetchRequest` and a `UITableView`.  There is good sample code for this in the documentation.  In this case you may find that the ordering of the data will take care of itself.  For instance say your table is ordered by "assignment date" (i.e. the date at which an employee was assigned to a boss) then simply creating the objects with the correct information would trigger the correct results in the table.

*Please note that ordered relationships do not work with iCloud.  However in my opinion iCloud doesn't work anyway so that's not a problem.*

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, actually I have an add to add boss and the employees assigned to him bu using an add button. I want to the new boss and employee added should always be at first position  in the table. I know I have to use insertObject:atIndex function, but in which method.Please reply

Comment: Edited answer to describe more about ordering data in core data and syncing the order in the table.  Note that the table and its data source have to match, so saying it has to be first in the table is the same as saying it has to be first in the datasource (i.e. be the cell returned when the table asks for the cell for the first row) How you keep datasource in sync depends on the data source (two common options described above) you keep the table in sync using the methods mentioned in the edited answer.  REMEMBER though the table and the datasource have to match or you will get errors.

Comment: please check I have added the code above where I create employee object, So If I have to make changes to the NSOrderedSet, whether it should be done here,please check the code above

Comment: So how does the table get its order in the first place?

Comment: hey thanks for you reply, whether I should write this in insertObject function?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: hey , In my above post, I have shown you a function called "InsertNewObject" and you have shown me how to insert every new employee at zero position, So, I want to know whether I should write this is "InsertNewObject" function

Comment: Yes, that looks like an appropriate place.  Also note that because you reload the whole table in your example, you negate the need for the more granular insert / move methods in my longer answer.  If you find the performance of reloading the whole table is a problem you can switch to those methods for inserting single rows into the table when you add your object to the data source.

Comment: hi, I tried adding those lines of code , but it is not working, application is crashing

Comment: Please check the above changes, my app is crashing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18977/discussion-between-ranjit-and-rory-obryan)

Comment: Thanks, But I have one more doubt, how to reorder bosses, and I dont want to take order attribute to maintain its order, because if I delete a boss item then I have to maintain that order attribute. any suggestions on how to proceed

Comment: If you use the ordered relationship feature of core data then the order is maintained for you.  Otherwise you have to manage the attributes yourself.  If bosses aren't part of an ordered relationship, perhaps you need to add another object to hang them from, even if it's just a 'MyApp' object...  MyApp.bosses ..

Comment: Now in my example boss-employee is a ordered one-to-many relationship, i.e a boss can have x number of employees. so now you are saying that I should take one more entity and make that entity and boss as ordered relationship.correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Correct if you want to use an ordered relationship to maintain the order of bosses automatically in your app (rather than use an ordering attribute on Boss and sort an NSFetchRequest) then there must be an ordered relationship to bosses.  If none exists then you need to create one.  Perhaps a 'Bosses' entity and have Bosses->Boss or a 'MyApp' entity and have MyApp->boss.  But yes if you want to use Ordered relationships then you need to have a relationship to order that goes from somewhere to somewhere.  Perhaps there is a natural object you haven't added to your model yet or just make one up.

Comment: I didnt get this line "Perhaps there is a natural object you haven't added to your model yet or just make one up."

Comment: Hello Rory, One more doubt, As you said I have added the MyApp entity, but already boss and employee have an ordered one-to-many relationship. So Now to make MyApp and boss as the ordered one-to-many relationship, whether I should add one more relationship in boss. i.e one relationship with employee and one with MyApp. Also let me know what happens to MyApp entity when I delete the boss items.

Comment: One more doubt, what should be the attributes of MyApp entity, what should go in it

Comment: Hey , I am thinking of using an float type attribute called displayOrder, So please help me out in how to increment it on each insert, Above I have added the code, but its not working, please check it and let me know whether I am doing it the right way

Comment: Hi Ranjit, this has probably strayed a bit too far from the original question into more general design questions for your app.  Probably best research any other questions to see if they are already answered and if not start some new questions.  I think you've got the general idea of what options are available for ordering in core data.  Last comment from me; when I said natural object I meant maybe there is a natural place to add a relationship to your bosses, perhaps "company" that you will use in your app anyway, if not you need to invent an object to hang the relationship off.

Comment: Oh, now you edited the question, my specific answer doesn't make sense!!